# [NestJS]Custom Parameter in Class Constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to pass custom arguments into a class that injects another service(ApiCallService).

```
export class FPCT {    
  constructor(
    payload: {
      isLive: boolean;
      exchangeReference?: string | number;
    },
    private apiCallService: ApiCallService,
  ) {}
}
```

ApiCallService is already added to the module provider but the service keeps returning `undefined` when I try to access it.

I have tried to add the `FPCT` class as a provider but nest complains about it not being able to define the first parameter(the `payload` object)

The first parameter(the `payload` object) is going to be passed from a controller

Comment: **you** need to understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to inject `ApiCallService` into an instance of `FPCT` by yourself (via `new FPCT()`) or using nestjs DI system?

Comment: i am trying to use the nestjs DI system

Comment: one way: add the `@Injectable()` to `FPCT` class and add it to the `providers` array. You'll need to move the `payload` field to a property field instead, otherwise you'll need to use `@Inject()` to inject a custom provider.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like this:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    FPCT,
    ApiCallService,
    {
      provide: 'payload',
      useValue: {
        isLive: true,
        exchangeReference: '1234',
      },
    },
  ],
})
export class MyModule {}
// ...
@Injectable()
export class FPCT {
  constructor(
    @Inject('payload')
    payload: {
      isLive: boolean;
      exchangeReference?: string | number;
    },
    private apiCallService: ApiCallService,
  ) {}
}
```

---

You could use [`ModuleRef#get`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#retrieving-instances), or `app.get(ApiCallService)`.

It all depends on what you're trying to do, which wasn't clear.